# Recursive AppData\Local\Application Data link - where should this point to?

Tags: windows-7, filesystem-corruption

I seem to have broken my Win7 home directory somewhat.

in my users folder at `AppData\Local\` there is a link from 'Application Data`to`AppData\Local` which leads to pathalogical paths such as

`C:\Users\Scott\AppData\Local\Application Data\Application Data\Application Data\Application Data\Application Data\Application Data`

What's the right way to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

This link should be in `C:\Users\Scott\` (unless you moved it accidentally). Open Command Prompt and use `move` to put it to the right place:

```
cd /d C:\Users\Scott
move "AppData\Local\Application Data" "."
```

The link is created for compatibility reasons: some broken programs written for Windows XP assume that the appdata directory name will never change.